# Cascade dropdown update and freeze VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have three combo boxes: **cbo_prefRoom1, cbo_prefRoom2, cbo_prefRoom3**.

On form initialisation **cbo_prefRoom2** and **cbo_prefRoom3** are disabled.

When the user selects an option in **cbo_prefRoom1** then it enables **cbo_prefRoom2**. 
When the user selects an option in **cbo_prefRoom2** then it enables **cbo_prefRoom3**.

What I would like to do is add an instance in which if the user selects the option `No Preference` in **cbo_prefRoom1** then what happens is **cbo_prefRoom2** and **cbo_prefRoom3** are updated with the same value of `No Preference`. Then **cbo_prefRoom2** and **cbo_prefRoom3** are disabled until the user changes the option of `No Preference` in **cbo_prefRoom1**.

There is also a second instance of this, if the user selects the option `No Preference` in **cbo_prefRoom2** then **cbo_prefRoom3** is updated with the same value of `No Preference` and disabled. Then **cbo_prefRoom3** is disabled until the user changes the option of `No Preference` in **cbo_prefRoom2**.

How do I go about achieving this?

```
Private Sub cbo_prefRoom1_Change()

' When user selects an option in cbo_prefRoom1 then cbo_prefRoom2 is enabled
    With cbo_prefRoom2
        .Enabled = Len(cbo_prefRoom1.Value) > 0
            If Not .Enabled Then
                .ListIndex = -1
            End If
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub cbo_prefRoom2_Change()

' When user selects an option in cbo_prefRoom2 then cbo_prefRoom3 is enabled
    With cbo_prefRoom3
        .Enabled = Len(cbo_prefRoom2.Value) > 0
            If Not .Enabled Then
                .ListIndex = -1
            End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean combo box instead of check box? A checkbox only has two values, true or false, but you mention a 'No preference' option which denotes at least three values.

Comment: @justnS Sorry I meant combo box

Comment: @justnS I checkbox can have three values if the TripleState option is set to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? You could also take the same idea and move it to the event for `cbo_prefRoom2` click event.

```
If cbo_prefRoom1.Value = "No Preference" Then
  cbo_prefRoom2.value = "No Preference"
  cbo_prefRoom3.value = "No Preference"
Else
  With cbo_prefRoom2
    .Enabled = Len(cbo_prefRoom1.Value) > 0
    If Not .Enabled Then
      .ListIndex = -1
    End If
  End With
End If
```

Comment: Will this disable `cbo_prefRoom2.value` and `cbo_prefRoom3.value` if `cbo_prefRoom1.value` is **No preference**?